# pytest @patch var inside route in FastApi

Tags: pytest, monkeypatching

I try to use `@path` from `unittest.mock` to mock (with return value) var inside `FastApi` route

route is:

```
from . import superlogic

@router.post('/{item_id}/submit'):
async def submit(item: str):
   var_i_need_to_mock = super_object.very_long_complicated_logic()
   return True // nevermid
```

pytest:

```
@patch('app.router.submit'):
def test_submit(test_client):
    var_i_need_to_mock = True
    test_client.post('/submit') // But var_i_need_to_mock doesn't overrides
```

I can patch my `super_object` instead of `var_i_need_to_mock` and it works as expected like below
`@patch('app.router.submit', mockobject)`

What is the best practice directly override `var_i_need_to_mock` inside route and how to achieve this

Comment: You can't override a local function variable (it doesn't even exist until the function has been called). In any case, you wouldn't expect setting a local variable in one function to have any impact on another function. You could mock `super_object.very_long_complicated_logic`. You may need to rewrite your code to make it more testable if you only want to override *some* logic in that method.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would try to patch the return value of `super_object.very_long_complicated_logic`, like so:

```py
@patch('filename.super_object.very_long_complicated_logic', return_value=True):
def test_submit(test_client):
    test_client.post('/submit')
```

Comment: yes, it works, and i could use it, but what if for some reason i  can't patch  very_long_complicated_logic. I need override directly

Comment: As @larsks wrote, `var_i_need_to_mock` is a local variable in the function, so it's not possible to overwrite it's value. What is the reason you can't patch `very_long_complicated_logic`?